# mp3 file showing red j attached

Tags: android, android-studio, android-assets

I added an audio file to the raw folder but wasn't able to reference it. When I checked it had a red circle with a "j" inside it.

[image]

When I reference the raw folder in Java it doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android Studio's settings.
choose file types
choose java source
remove .mp3 under the registered patterns.
you are good to go.